# How to be able to upload a batch of images fast in filepond? (500 images)

Tags: javascript, laravel, filepond

What are the things to consider to be able to upload a batch of images faster in filepond? to be able to upload 500 images faster into the server on one submission.

Comment: Don't use FilePond. I don't think the developers of the lib were thinking of 500 files. Ask the user to upload a zip or something.

Comment: Developer of FilePond here. Can confirm what @code said, I didn't build FilePond for situations where you upload hundreds of files. If these are directories maybe the FilePond zip plugin can help, https://github.com/tzsk/filepond-plugin-zipper

Comment: @code Thank you so much for your comments and suggestions will do that.

Comment: @Rik Thank you so much for your comments and suggestions will do that.
I'll try to use that plugin.